# Can I open two pdf documents using visual basic 2008 with just one menu click?

Tags: vb.net

I have a common.vb member that contains a number of different links (menu) to various forms or to a pdf. One link (Bidding Opportunities) currently opens one pdf. I need for that link to open another pdf in a separate window just like the current one. In other words two separate pdfs in two separate windows. Everything I've tried so far has not worked. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Current Code Example=

```
    Dim MenuItem17 As String = "<a href='" & "http://docs.birminghamal.gov/landbank/RFPforLegalServicesforBLBAQuietTitleActions.pdf" & " ' target='_blank'>" & "Bidding Opportunities" & "</a></br><br>"
```

Comment: VB.NET  ?  Not VBA...

Comment: You would need some scripting for this i think.